# How can I limit the number of features I see in the bounding box with a WMS layer?

Tags: postgresql, leaflet, postgis, geoserver, wms

I set up a PostGIS database that I added in GeoServer via a parameterized SQL view. I used Leaflet to display this layer via wms and it works fine.

Now I would like to limit the number of features I see in the bounding box (25 maximum in my case).

I had a hope with the maxFeatures vendor parameter for wms proposed in geoserver but apparently it controls the number of features on each tile not in the bouding box. I also tried to add a LIMIT 25 at the end of my SQL view but it affects the number of features on the whole map not in the bouding box.

Is there a way to do what I want with a wms layer?

Thanks,

Comment: Since Leaflet makes one WMS request per tile, that parameter is limiting the number of features in the **tile's bounding box**, therefore working exactly as expected. Look into https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms 's "single-tile" mode. Beware of the cons of re-requesting big parts of the viewport.

Comment: Thanks it corresponds to the behavior I'm looking for!